# An Inequality related to the Cantor Set $\mathscr C \subset [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, cantor-set

> Let $\mathscr C\subset\mathbb R$ be the Cantor set on the interval $[0,1]$. Let $x\in \mathscr C$, and $0 < r < 1$ such that $$\frac{2}{3^k} < r \le \frac{2}{3^{k-1}}$$
> for some positive integer $k$. Recall that $\mathscr C = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k$, where $E_k$ consists of intervals of length $3^{-k}$.
>
> 1. Show that the interval $B(x,r) := [x-r,x+r]$ overlaps one of the intervals in the complement of $E_{k-1}$ by *at least* $$\delta = \min\{r - 3^{-k}, 3^{-(k-1)}\}$$
> 2. Further, show that $\delta \ge \frac r 2$.

*My work.*

Assuming $(1)$ holds, I could show $(2)$.

- By the choice of $k$, $3^{-(k-1)}\ge \frac r 2$.
- Also, $r > 2\cdot 3^{-k}$ implies that $\frac r 2 > 3^{-k}$. Subtracting $r$ on both sides, $r - 3^{-k} \ge \frac r 2$.

Therefore, $\delta \ge \frac r2$. Could someone help me show $(1)$?
A pictorial explanation or something along those lines may help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about the case when $k=2$, $x=\frac{1}{9}$, $r=\frac{1}{3}$ ? In this case there is exactly one interval outside $E_{k-1}$, namely $J=[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]$, and the overlap between $J$ and $[x-r,x+r]=[\frac{-2}{9},\frac{4}{9}]$ is exactly $\frac{4}{9}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{9}$, and this is strictly smaller than $\delta=\min(r-\frac{1}{3^k},\frac{1}{3^{k-1}})=\min(\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3})=\frac{2}{9}$. So your claim is false as stated now.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy My claim is based on Example 3.11 in Falconer's Fractal Geometry. If you have a copy, please take a look. I shall add more details soon.

Comment: I don't have Falconer's book, but since my counterexample is fully detailed and also rather simple, it should be easy for you to spot a mistake in it if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to give an explaination with some figures. In the following two lines, I try to show you what $E_k$ and $E_{k-1}$ looks like on the same part of the real axis. "[--$E_k$--]" represents a closed interval in $E_k$, while "(--$\mathbb{R}\setminus E_k$--)" represents an open interval of $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_k$. Note that the long open interval on the right is contained in both $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_k$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_{k-1}$.

[--$E_k$--](-$\mathbb{R}\setminus E_k$-)[--$E_k$--](------$\mathbb{R}\setminus E_k$------)
[-------------$E_{k-1}$-----------](-----$\mathbb{R}\setminus E_{k-1}$-----)

Since $x\in \mathscr{C}$, we have $x\in E_k$. Suppose $x$ lies in the right interval of $E_k$ in the figure. Then the length of $[x-r,x+r]\setminus E_{k-1}$ is at least $r-3^{-k}$ (It reaches the minimum $r-3^{-k}$ when $x$ is the left endpoint.) Since the intervals of $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_{k-1}$ has a minimum length $3^{-(k-1)}$, the overlapping length is at least $\min\{r-3^{-k},3^{-(k-1)}\}$.